# Django jquery not working

Tags: jquery, django

I have a problem with jQuery in my project
as I can't successfully call any js function. I have added the jquery library to `home.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js' %} ">
    </script>
```

and I try to call something like:

```
{% extends "posts/home.html" %}


{% block content %}
<select onchange="dzialaj()">
    {% for author in users %}
        <option value={{author.id}}>{{author.username}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<div id='posty'>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

but calling even a simple alert() doesn't give any result.

my settings static conf:

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'


CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'



STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_env","static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_pro", "my_static"),
    #'/var/www/static/',
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_env","media_root")
```

i have loaded static files in my base template too

update:
I found that this problem can be a bug in python 2.7 Does someone know how to fix it?

Comment: Do you get any error in your browser's console?

Comment: coud you add structure of your app, please? precisely the `static` folder structure

Comment: No i don't get any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Check staticfile_dirs in your settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Your template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js' %} ">
</script>
```

Comment: I have load static files in my base template and i have configured static files too.

Comment: But on your console appears js being called with status 200?

Comment: I'm not sure what do u mean but when  start load my page on chrome in console i have somethin like this
/posts/HTTP/1.1 200 4894
/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js HTTP/1.1 404 2079

Comment: I think your problem is in your static configuration
On your console your js should appear: /static/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js HTTP/1.1 404...
Try calling this file by url:
localhost:8000/static/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js

Comment: Of course  i get 404 error. But what is interesting when i try to get to other static files, images for example there's no problem with that.